# Single session between Chrome extension and Web pages possible?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Didn't find any similar question.

I will be creating a production Chrome extension for the first time and wanted to know if my company's login session can be shared between both webpages and extensions. Currently there is both Google authentication and a normal authentication on the company login page but I assume I only have to consider session and cookies.

If a user is logged in from the site, the extension should show logged in too and vice versa. The extension will also display login screen if user isn't logged in anywhere.

Is it bad practice by any chance?

Comment: This reminds me of the current problem where youtubers get their session stolen and bad actor log into their account. It all depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: So I assume bad practice?